# Angular 7 test case throwing broadcaster error

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular7, testcase

while running test cases it throws this error.
Almost added all required components and services and other dependencies though it is throwing error while running test-cases in Angular &

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Broadcaster]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Broadcaster]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Broadcaster!
```

[image]

**this is spec file code**

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';


import {CustomiseMenuComponent} from './customise-menu.component';

describe('CustomiseMenuComponent', () => {
    let component: CustomiseMenuComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CustomiseMenuComponent>;

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {path: 'designs', component: CustomiseMenuComponent}
    ];

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                CustomiseMenuComponent,
            ],
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                HttpClientModule,
                RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CustomiseMenuComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: We kind of need your component & module code to help you. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is Broadcaster a service you created with that name or some sort? I could't find any reference form Angular with that name.

Comment: @GonzaloMuro: yes I made that service, I got solution of it, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the key phrase: "**No provider for Broadcaster!**". I suppose, you should add the Broadcaster to the "providers" array in the "AppModule" file.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    Broadcaster,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
```

**Update:** Maybe you can check the doc here, if you are using this service:
https://github.com/ranbuch/ng-broadcaster

[image: Broadcater - Error Suggestion]

Comment: can you elaborate more? and give syntax please?

Comment: I am not sure how to put it other way - not being familiar with Angular testing. The "Broadcaster" service should be added to the "providers" array in your app's (or module's) main ".module.ts" file.